# PHP: Compare two sets of numbers, no dupes

Tags: php, numbers, compare

I'm creating a lottery contest for my site, and I need to know the easiest way to compare numbers, so that no two people can choose the same numbers. It's 7 sets of numbers, each number is a number between 1 and 30.

For example, if user 1 chooses:   1, 7, 9, 17, 22, 25, 29  how can I make sure that user 2 can't choose those same exact number?

I was thinking about throwing all 7 numbers into an array, sort it so the numbers are in order, then join them into one string. Then when another user chooses their 7 numbers, it does the same, then compares the two. Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you describe sounds like the best way to me, **IF** you are dealing with all submissions in the same script - I would `trim(implode(',',$array))` the sorted array, store the resulting string in an array and call `in_array()` to determine whether the value already exists.

**HOWEVER** I suspect that what you are actually doing is storing the selections in a database table and comparing later submissions against this table. In this case (I am taking a liberty and assuming MySQL here but I would say it is the most common engine used with PHP) you should create a table with 7 columns `choice_1`, `choice_2` ... `choice_7`(along with whatever other columns you want) and create a unique index across *all seven* `choice_*` columns. This means that when you try and insert a duplicate row, the query will fail. This lets MySQL do all the work for you.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned the MySQL. Yes, plan on storing it in a database.

6 of the numbers can be the same, just not all 7. Wouldn't putting a unique index on all 7 columns not allow any dupes?

User 1 can have 1, 7, 9, 17, 22, 25, 29 while user 2 can have 1, 7, 9, 17, 22, 25, 30. Just all 7 can't be the same.

Comment: Yes creating a multi-column unique index allows for this. In order for an insert to fail, all 7 columns have to be the same as another entry.

Comment: Makes sense. What about order? Will 1, 7, 9, 17, 22, 25, 29 and 7, 1, 9, 25, 22, 17, 29 (same numbers, different order) still cause it to fail?

Comment: Yes you would need to make sure the values were in the same order - but your original suggestion of putting the user's submission into an array and sorting it can easily ensure this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php). There are some really good examples on php.net.